# Suspension preload options

Tags: fork, suspension

I have a Schwinn GTX3 Hardtail with a M3010 Suntour fork. I looked up the model number on the back of the left leg and it is supposed to have a preload adjuster available. However, mine does not for some reason. I was wondering if it would be possible to install a preload adjuster or lockout if I buy the parts, even if it does not have them on currently. (Btw: The fork is the one that originally came with the bike model.)

Answer (score 1):

The following exploded [diagram](https://www.srsuntour.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Consumer/Bike/Exploded%20views/2015/Suspension%20Fork/SF15-M3010/SF15-M3010-A-P-26-50%2C63-%281%29.PDF) for something called SR Suntour SF15-M3010-A-P-26-50 lists a "CONTROL ADJUST SYSTEM" as part number FKE007-11 . Depending on whether your fork is a compatible one or not, this might be the part your are looking after.

[image: pdf]

Comment: I looked at my bike and I realized that both sides of my cap had the fixing caps, while the model there has a preload adjuster on one side. Since it is the same model, would it be possible to simply buy the part from amazon or a bike dealer and install it? From the looks of it, my fork has all the same parts except for the preload adjuster.

Comment: Well, it is hard to tell for sure unless the internals of two forks are identical. You can disassemble your fork to learn this for yourself. You are likely to need a special tool to undo the top caps, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tABGvESjL4o

Comment: @C4Patino For the cost of buying all the tools, parts, oils, etc, you'd be much better off just buying a whole new better fork.